# .NET DLL Injector in C++

Tags: c++, .net, windows, dynamic-loading, ffi

I built a DLL Injector with User-Interface.
The program lists all processes, the user chooses one of them and a DLL, and inject it.
It's my first project in C++, and I know it's not exactly C++ because it runs with .NET, but still.

Please look for efficiency problems, memory leaks, or irregular coding standard.

Full Code:
[DLL Injector](https://github.com/gilmansharov/DLL_Injector/tree/ce7e9f9b2b3b8444c2adadb947c52a0f471918db)

These are the important classes:

**CustomProcess.cpp**

```
> #include "CustomProcess.h"
//Process list maximum size
#define ARRAY_SIZE  300


/**
 * 2 parameters constructor:
 * Process Name and a Process ID
 */
CustomProcess::CustomProcess(System::String^ processName, DWORD processID)
{
    this->_name = processName;
    this->_id = processID;
}

//Inject a given DLL to the process
bool CustomProcess::injectDLL(System::String^ DLL_PATH)
{
    //Handle to the process
    HANDLE hProcess;

    //Handle to the remote thread we'll create
    HANDLE hRemote;

    LPVOID paramAddr;
    // Instance to kernel32.dll - to get the LoadLibraryA function from
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary("KERNEL32");

    //Function pointer to the "LoadLibraryA" function at the kernel32.dll
    fpLoadLibrary loadLibraryAddr = (fpLoadLibrary)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "LoadLibraryA");


    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, this->_id);
    if (hProcess == nullptr)
        return false;

    paramAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, DLL_PATH->Length + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (paramAddr == nullptr)
        CustomProcess::collectGarbage(hProcess, nullptr, nullptr);

    //WriteProcessMemory doesn't accepts System::String^ object, so let's convert it to char array
    char* ch = new char[DLL_PATH->Length + 1];
    copyString(DLL_PATH, ch);

    BOOL written = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, paramAddr, ch, DLL_PATH->Length, NULL);

    if (!written)
    {
        CustomProcess::collectGarbage(hProcess, nullptr, ch);
        return false;
    }


    try
    {
        hRemote = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLibraryAddr, paramAddr, 0, 0);
        if (!hRemote)
        if (!ntCreateRemoteThreadEx(hProcess, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLibraryAddr, paramAddr))
        {
            CustomProcess::collectGarbage(hProcess, hRemote, ch);
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception^ e)
    {
        delete e;
        CustomProcess::collectGarbage(hProcess, hRemote, ch);
        return false;
    }
    CustomProcess::collectGarbage(hProcess, hRemote, ch);

    return true;

}


//Closing Handles and get rid of the memory we allocated for the injectDLL function
void CustomProcess::collectGarbage(HANDLE hProcess, HANDLE hRemote, char* ch)
{
    if (hProcess != nullptr)
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    if (hRemote != nullptr)
        CloseHandle(hRemote);
    if (ch != nullptr)
        delete ch;
}


/**
 * This function gets a System::String^ Object as a source and a char array as a destination,
 * and copies the chars in the string to the char array
 */
void CustomProcess::copyString(System::String^ str, char* dest)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str->Length; i++)
        dest[i] = static_cast<char>(str[i]);
}

/**
 * Creates remote thread for x64 processes.
 */
HANDLE CustomProcess::ntCreateRemoteThreadEx(HANDLE hHandle, LPVOID loadLibAddr, LPVOID dllPathAddr) {

    HANDLE hRemoteThread = NULL;

    LPVOID ntCreateThreadExAddr = NULL;
    DWORD temp1 = 0;
    DWORD temp2 = 0;
    NtCreateThreadExBuffer ntbuffer;
    ntCreateThreadExAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")), "NtCreateThreadEx");

    //Call to ntCreateThreadEx function succeeded
    if (ntCreateThreadExAddr) {

        ntbuffer.Size = sizeof(NtCreateThreadExBuffer);
        ntbuffer.Unknown1 = 0x10003;
        ntbuffer.Unknown2 = 0x8;
        ntbuffer.Unknown3 = &temp2;
        ntbuffer.Unknown4 = 0;
        ntbuffer.Unknown5 = 0x10004;
        ntbuffer.Unknown6 = 4;
        ntbuffer.Unknown7 = &temp1;
        ntbuffer.Unknown8 = 0;

        LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx funNtCreateThreadEx = (LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx)ntCreateThreadExAddr;
        NTSTATUS status = funNtCreateThreadEx(
            &hRemoteThread,
            0x1FFFFF,
            NULL,
            hHandle,
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLibAddr,
            dllPathAddr,
            FALSE,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &ntbuffer
            );

        if (hRemoteThread == NULL) 
        {
            // NtCreateRemoteThreadEx Failed!
            return NULL;
        }
        else 
        {
            //NtCreateRemoteThreadEx Succeeded!
            return hRemoteThread;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);
    return NULL;

}


//Get Process ID
DWORD CustomProcess::getPID()
{
    return this->_id;
}

//Set Process ID
void CustomProcess::setPID(DWORD pid)
{
    this->_id = pid;
}

//Get Process Name
System::String^ CustomProcess::getName()
{
    return this->_name;
}

//Set Process Name
void CustomProcess::setName(System::String^ processName)
{
    this->_name = (processName != nullptr) ? processName : this->_name;
}


//Returns description of the Process in this format: "[Process Name] <-> [Process ID]"
System::String^ CustomProcess::ToString()
{
    System::String^ str = this->_name + " <-> " + this->_id;
    return str;
}


//Generates a list of all the running processes in the system
array<CustomProcess^>^ CustomProcess::getProcessList()
{
    array<CustomProcess ^> ^ process_list = gcnew array<CustomProcess ^>(ARRAY_SIZE);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = { sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32) };
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    int i = 0;
    if (Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
    {
        do
        {
            process_list[i] = gcnew CustomProcess(gcnew System::String(pe32.szExeFile), pe32.th32ProcessID);
            i++;
        } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
    return process_list;
}
```

**CustomProcess.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

ref class CustomProcess
{
public:
    CustomProcess(System::String^ processName, DWORD processID);
    bool injectDLL(System::String^ DLL_PATH);
    static array<CustomProcess^>^ getProcessList();

    DWORD getPID();
    void setPID(DWORD pid);
    System::String^ getName();
    void setName(System::String^ processName);

    System::String^ ToString() override;

private:
    System::String^ _name;
    DWORD _id;

    typedef HINSTANCE (*fpLoadLibrary)(char*);

    value struct NtCreateThreadExBuffer {
        ULONG Size;
        ULONG Unknown1;
        ULONG Unknown2;
        PULONG Unknown3;
        ULONG Unknown4;
        ULONG Unknown5;
        ULONG Unknown6;
        PULONG Unknown7;
        ULONG Unknown8;
    };

    typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI *LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx) (
        OUT PHANDLE hThread,
        IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
        IN LPVOID ObjectAttributes,
        IN HANDLE ProcessHandle,
        IN LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
        IN LPVOID lpParameter,
        IN BOOL CreateSuspended,
        IN ULONG StackZeroBits,
        IN ULONG SizeOfStackCommit,
        IN ULONG SizeOfStackReserve,
        OUT LPVOID lpBytesBuffer
        );

    void collectGarbage(HANDLE hProcess, HANDLE hRemote, char* ch);
    void copyString(System::String^ str, char* dest);

    HANDLE ntCreateRemoteThreadEx(HANDLE hHandle, LPVOID loadLibAddr, LPVOID dllPathAddr);

};
```

**MyForm.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "CustomProcess.h"
#include "Form_Instructions.h"
#include "Form_About.h"


namespace DLL_Injector {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::IO;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    protected:

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  buttonInject;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ListView^  listView1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  buttonOpenDLL;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^  openDLL;
    private: System::String^ DLL_PATH;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  dll_path_box;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  buttonRefresh;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ListView^  listProgress;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  helpToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  instructionsToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  aboutToolStripMenuItem;
    protected:


    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm::typeid));
            this->buttonInject = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->listView1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListView());
            this->buttonOpenDLL = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->openDLL = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog());
            this->dll_path_box = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->buttonRefresh = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->listProgress = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListView());
            this->menuStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip());
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->instructionsToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->aboutToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->menuStrip1->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // buttonInject
            // 
            this->buttonInject->AutoSize = true;
            this->buttonInject->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->buttonInject->Enabled = false;
            this->buttonInject->Location = System::Drawing::Point(272, 36);
            this->buttonInject->Name = L"buttonInject";
            this->buttonInject->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->buttonInject->TabIndex = 1;
            this->buttonInject->Text = L"Inject";
            this->buttonInject->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this->buttonInject->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // listView1
            // 
            this->listView1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(38, 103);
            this->listView1->Name = L"listView1";
            this->listView1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(239, 381);
            this->listView1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->listView1->UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this->listView1->SelectedIndexChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // buttonOpenDLL
            // 
            this->buttonOpenDLL->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->buttonOpenDLL->Location = System::Drawing::Point(410, 36);
            this->buttonOpenDLL->Name = L"buttonOpenDLL";
            this->buttonOpenDLL->Size = System::Drawing::Size(111, 23);
            this->buttonOpenDLL->TabIndex = 3;
            this->buttonOpenDLL->Text = L"Choose DLL";
            this->buttonOpenDLL->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this->buttonOpenDLL->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::buttonOpenDLL_Click);
            // 
            // openDLL
            // 
            this->openDLL->FileName = L"DLL_PATH";
            this->openDLL->Filter = L"DLL File|*.dll";
            this->openDLL->Title = L"Choose Your DLL";
            // 
            // dll_path_box
            // 
            this->dll_path_box->Location = System::Drawing::Point(38, 77);
            this->dll_path_box->Name = L"dll_path_box";
            this->dll_path_box->ReadOnly = true;
            this->dll_path_box->Size = System::Drawing::Size(542, 22);
            this->dll_path_box->TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // buttonRefresh
            // 
            this->buttonRefresh->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->buttonRefresh->Location = System::Drawing::Point(113, 36);
            this->buttonRefresh->Name = L"buttonRefresh";
            this->buttonRefresh->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->buttonRefresh->TabIndex = 5;
            this->buttonRefresh->Text = L"Refresh";
            this->buttonRefresh->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this->buttonRefresh->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::buttonRefresh_Click);
            // 
            // listProgress
            // 
            this->listProgress->Location = System::Drawing::Point(339, 103);
            this->listProgress->Name = L"listProgress";
            this->listProgress->Size = System::Drawing::Size(241, 381);
            this->listProgress->TabIndex = 6;
            this->listProgress->UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this->listProgress->Columns->Add("Logs");
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this->menuStrip1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(1) { this->helpToolStripMenuItem });
            this->menuStrip1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
            this->menuStrip1->Name = L"menuStrip1";
            this->menuStrip1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(616, 24);
            this->menuStrip1->TabIndex = 7;
            this->menuStrip1->Text = L"menuStrip1";
            // 
            // helpToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem->DropDownItems->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(2) {
                this->instructionsToolStripMenuItem,
                    this->aboutToolStripMenuItem
            });
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"helpToolStripMenuItem";
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(43, 20);
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"Help";
            // 
            // instructionsToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->instructionsToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"instructionsToolStripMenuItem";
            this->instructionsToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(152, 22);
            this->instructionsToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"Instructions";
            this->instructionsToolStripMenuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::instructionsToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // aboutToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->aboutToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"aboutToolStripMenuItem";
            this->aboutToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(152, 22);
            this->aboutToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"About";
            this->aboutToolStripMenuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::GradientInactiveCaption;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(616, 511);
            this->Controls->Add(this->listProgress);
            this->Controls->Add(this->buttonRefresh);
            this->Controls->Add(this->dll_path_box);
            this->Controls->Add(this->buttonOpenDLL);
            this->Controls->Add(this->listView1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->buttonInject);
            this->Controls->Add(this->menuStrip1);
            this->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Segoe UI", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
            this->MainMenuStrip = this->menuStrip1;
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"DLL Injector";
            this->menuStrip1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->menuStrip1->PerformLayout();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion


    System::String^ current;
    array<CustomProcess^>^ process_list;


    //Inject
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        this->listProgress->View = View::Details;
        this->listProgress->Columns[0]->Width = this->listView1->Width - 4;
        int count = 0;
        buttonRefresh_Click(nullptr, nullptr);
        for (int i = 0; ((i < process_list->Length) && (process_list[i] != nullptr)); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                System::String^ str1 = process_list[i]->ToString();
                System::String^ str2 = current;

                if (str1->Equals(str2))
                {

                    if (!process_list[i]->injectDLL(DLL_PATH))
                    {
                        this->listProgress->Items->Add("Couldn't Inject DLL To: " + process_list[i]->ToString());
                        this->listProgress->Items->Add("Maybe you don't have permissions?");
                        Sleep(500);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox::Show("DLL Injected Successfully!");
                        this->listProgress->Items->Add("DLL Injected To: " + process_list[i]->ToString());
                        this->buttonInject->Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception^ e)
            {
                MessageBox::Show(e->Message);
            }
        }
    }


    private: System::Void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        if (listView1->SelectedItems->Count > 0)
            current = listView1->SelectedItems[0]->Text;
        isOkayToInject();
    }

    private: void isOkayToInject()
    {
        if (listView1->SelectedItems->Count < 1)
             return;
        else if (DLL_PATH == nullptr)
            return;
        else
            this->buttonInject->Enabled = true;
    }


    private: System::Void buttonOpenDLL_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        if (openDLL->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
        {
            DLL_PATH = openDLL->FileName;
            this->dll_path_box->Text = DLL_PATH;
            isOkayToInject();
        }
    }


    private: System::Void buttonRefresh_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        this->listView1->Clear();
        this->listView1->View = View::Details;
        this->listView1->Columns->Add("Process Name <-> PID");
        this->listView1->Columns[0]->Width = this->listView1->Width - 4;
        process_list = CustomProcess::getProcessList();
        for (int i = 0; i < process_list->Length; i++)
        {
            if (process_list[i] == nullptr)
                break;
            this->listView1->Items->Add(process_list[i]->ToString());
        }
    }


    private: System::Void instructionsToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        DLL_Injector::Form_Instructions^ instructions = gcnew DLL_Injector::Form_Instructions();
        instructions->ShowDialog();
    }

    private: System::Void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        DLL_Injector::Form_About^ about = gcnew DLL_Injector::Form_About();
        about->ShowDialog();
    }
};
}
```

Comment: `I know it's not exactly C++ because it runs with .NET, but still.` So it is actually C# and not C++? In that case you should probably remove the C++ tag in favor of a C# one.

Comment: It *is* C++, not C#, .NET is language agnostic.